# Shutdown firefox but on next launch, one time restore session

Tags: firefox-addon

In firefox, if you restart it, it will come back with the same session restored as much as possible. It does this without changing the preference to "restore session on startup". Is there a way for an addon to do this trick on firefox? I need to shut it down but on next launch it should restore session. I need to do so without changing the preference of:

[image]

My user has clicked a button to restart Aurora/firefox.exe into Nigtly/firefox.exe so im trying to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var appStartup = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/toolkit/app-startup;1"]
                 .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAppStartup);
appStartup.quit(Ci.nsIAppStartup.eAttemptQuit | Ci.nsIAppStartup.eRestart);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIAppStartup#Constants for a couple of other restart related options.

Comment: Thanks lucky man but this doesnt allow us to change the exe path? Forgive that I should have moved my last sentence to the topic title.

Comment: This is how I was doing one session restart: `var cancelQuit = Cc['@mozilla.org/supports-PRBool;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsISupportsPRBool); Services.obs.notifyObservers(cancelQuit, 'quit-application-requested', null); if (!cancelQuit.data) { Services.obs.notifyObservers(null, 'quit-application-granted', null); Services.startup.quit(Ci.nsIAppStartup.eAttemptQuit | Ci.nsIAppStartup.eRestart);
}` but this actually restarts. I need it to just mark everything to restore then i want to quit the app and launch another exe into this profile and all shud restore

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I misunderstood the switch from Aurora into Nightly on your last line. I see now that you want to launch a different application rather than the existing one so it doesn't look like nsIAppStartup can help unfortunately. Do you have code running in both applications? If so, you could just set that "restore session on startup" preference back to its original setting once the new application has launched?

Comment: Thanks @Luckyrat! Ah ok thats a good idea, yep its the same profile so my addon is present. However he might be restarting into safe mode in which case my addon would be disabled :(